# Does typename have to be specified inside template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

It seems that GCC does not require a typename to be specified inside the template while Clang does.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template<
    typename T,
    typename value_type = T::value_type
>
void func(T t) {}
```

The code above compiles successfully on GCC 10.0.1 when Clang reports the following error message:

```
❯ clang++ -std=c++20 asdf.cpp
asdf.cpp:3:27: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'T::value_type'
    typename value_type = T::value_type
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          typename
1 error generated.
```

Why is this so?

UPDATE 1:

As noted by @Language Lawyer, the first suspicion about `typename` is a feature of [P0634R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html) not currently supported by Clang.

UPDATE 2:

I'm going to separate this question as it contains two different topics.

See edit history for more details.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20 tells that P0634R3 is not supported in Clang yet

Comment: See also https://reviews.llvm.org/D53847

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Clear now. So the `typename` one is not a bug, but a feature not yet released in Clang.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I can accept your answer since the question title says `typename` only. Maybe I can post another question for the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++20 removes the need for specifying `typename` for dependent template names in specific cases where it's obvious that what is being specified *must* be a typename. Like, for example, [a template parameter's default value when that parameter has already specified that it is a `typename`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#5):

> A qualified name is said to be in a type-id-only context if it appears in [...] **default argument of a type-parameter of a template**, [...]

Clang [has not yet implemented this feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), but GCC has.